# adding spring-data-rest ontop of spring-data-jpa

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

i created a maven project, and added all dependencies i need.
i have some repositories using the spring-data-jpa, and i added some integration tests.

now i need to add ontop of it spring-data-rest, if i understand it is based on springmvc.
but all examples i found, i need to add spring boot to start the app.
i noticed also all new spring projects use spring boot.
this means that i have to learn and use it for my projects?

how can i use spring-data-jpa+spring-data-jpa with an existing servlet3 project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason all examples are written using Boot is that Boot *is* indeed the way you should start a new Spring project these days. It free's from a lot of the tedious work of setting up the infrastructure, finding dependencies in the right version etc.

To use Spring Data REST without Boot, simply add the necessary dependencies to your project. The easiest way to do this is to use the Spring Data Release Train BOM (which will help you pulling in the correct matching versions) along side the version-less dependency declarations for Spring Data REST WebMVC and - in your case - Spring Data JPA.

Then go ahead and either register `RepositoryRestMvcConvfiguration` as Spring bean (either through XML configuration or JavaConfig).

All of this is also documented in the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started.maven).